# Visual Studio Error: Unable to load arguments for the XmlPeek task. One of XmlContent or XmlInputPath arguments must be set

Tags: visual-studio

I opened up VS today to find this error waiting for me when I built my project. I hadn't changed anything since yesterday, when it was working just fine.

`Unable to load arguments for the XmlPeek task. One of XmlContent or XmlInputPath arguments must be set.`

Of course this error has no line associated with it or anything else that may be helpful...

The project is in the .NET 4 Framework with Console Output.

Any ideas as to what is going on? I tried googling this of course but the few answered I found had to do with a content pipeline (which this project does not use).

Thanks!

Comment: Copied the project's contents, deleted it, and pasted said contents into a new version of the project. Works fine now. Will leave question open if any real answers are out there.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error in case, when I have deleted Content Project of my game. It has been solved by adding correct content reference into the **Content References** directory.

I had two projects (`proj1` and `proj2`) and each of them had their own content projects (`proj1_content` and `proj2_content`). I wanted to have one common content project for both projects, so I had deleted both `proj1_content` and `proj2_content` and created new content project called `common_content`. After that, mentioned error appeared. Solution was to go to **Content References** directory at each project and **Add Content Reference** pointing to `common_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a hardware problem I had to put in a new SSD and re-installed VS.  All my projects worked except my XNA in Winforms project.  Being rather large (12,000 hand-written lines of code) really didn't want to try the "copy it all in to a new project" solution above.  Thought I'd try to see what versions worked.  All versions prior to me adding an installer project worked.  In fact, the version where I had added, then deleted the installer was broken.  So I'm not sure how (or if) the installer broke it but I found one section of the main project file that had a missing entry and it did reference XNA also (all my non-XNA projects build just fine).  Note that I have substituted my project's name with a reference to YOUR projects name by using <YourMainProjectName>.  If your project is joesgreatproject then use that text in place of <YourMainProjectName> (don't include the <> symbols).  I think this was only because the XNA didn't have a content directory and needed a reference to one.

File: <YourMainProjectName>.csproj

<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\< YourMainProjectName>Content\<YourMainProjectName>Content.contentproj">
      <Name><YourMainProjectName>Content</Name>
      <XnaReferenceType>Content</XnaReferenceType>
   </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>